# How to get control index in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Panel with a collection of controls in it.  How can I get the index of a specific control when iterating through them?  I'm using `foreach` to iterate, but there's no Index property.  Should I use `for x = 0...` and return `x` when my match is made, or what?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you only need the index in the Controls collection?  There may be a better way to attack your problem.

Answer (score 7):

You could use:

```
panel.Controls.IndexOf(control);
```

Or you could iterate over them with a for loop instead of a foreach loop.  Or you could just create an index that you increment inside of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the IndexOf method. Something like panel1.Controls.IndexOf(textBox1);

Answer (score 1):

To answer the specific question you asked, yes, I'd use

for(x = 0; x < panel.Controls.Count; i++)

However, if you are dynamically ading controls to the panel, you might consider giving them unique names or other identifing attributes via the .Name or .Tag properties.

Then you can discriminate among your child controls with more precision.

Hope this helps...